# CPtrList cannot use: error C2248: 'CObject::operator =' : cannot access private member declared in class 'CObject'

Tags: c++, mfc

I have an MFC project. So in this project I have created an isolated C++ class (one source file one header file), not MFC class. And in this C++ class header file I declared a CPtrList (without even using it in source file), but when it comes to compilation, there comes the error: C2248: 'CObject::operator =' : cannot access private member declared in class 'CObject'.

All I have is a declaration. I initially thought it was because that I should #include "afxcoll.h" at the beginning of the header file but it was not after trying.

No idea what's wrong. Any help please?

below is the header file. wouldnt compile.

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv\cv.h>
#include <opencv\highgui.h>
#include "stdafx.h"

class CMonitor
{
public:
CMonitor(void);
~CMonitor(void);

int horizontalPartition;
int verticalPartition;
int height;
int width;
int differenceThreshold;

bool intrusionIndicator;
bool setMatDimension;
bool setPartition;

int dequePresetSize;
//std::deque<cv::Mat> matDeque;
//CPtrList pMatList;

//Testing purposes:
int currentAvg;
int historyAvg;

void DrawGrid(cv::Mat& img, int verticalPartitionNo, int horizontalPartitionNo);
void PutDebugText(cv::Mat& img);

void MonitorDatabaseUpdate(cv::Mat img);
int SingleCellInHistoryDatabaseAvgComputing(int top, int left, int bottom, int right);
int SingleCellAvgComputing(int top, int left, int bottom, int right);
bool CMonitor::Detector();

void SetPartitionInfo(int horizontalPartition, int verticalPartition);
```

};

Comment: Delete line 5. That's were the error is... ok, seriously, are you looking for programming experts or fortune tellers? How would we know without looking at the code?

Comment: Show code! (and next time you post a question, a little common sense wouldn't go amiss).

Comment: Your "not MFC class" assumption is incorrect. CPtrList is derived from CObject. That makes it an MFC class. The answer from Mr.C64 has good advice.

Comment: i have attached the code for the header file. everyone please have a look..

Answer (score 1):

So, do you have a custom class inside of which you use a `CPtrList` data member?

Then, from the error message, probably you are trying to copy your class, and the compiler can't do that because `CPtrList` (as several other old MFC containers) is not-copyable.

I really suggest using **STL containers** instead of MFC containers (which cannot be copied, and some even use some form of "horror" `memcpy()` for copy!).

In your case, you may want to consider `std::vector` or `std::list`.

Comment: no i have nothing there other than a declaration.. but the declaration is in my costum class's header file